# How to skip(m).take(n) from a List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq

Given:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

How do I implement the following code?

```
var list2 = list.skip(2).take(5);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your sample code will work as long as you include `System.Linq` in your using statements (and fix your method names `.Skip(2)` and `.Take(5)`).

The reason your code did not work out of the box is that `.Skip` and `.Take` are extension methods (as opposed to methods defined in the List class) found in the 'System.Linq' namespace.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the samples in the following link and its more easy to go with

LINQ 101 Sample

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx